# Можно ли задать пользовательскую функцию внутри метода валидации jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation

Как задать пользовательскую функцию внутри метода валидации, которая вызывалась бы вместе с этим методом при проверке ошибок? Или как вызвать функцию после успешной валидации ВСЕХ полей? Дефолтный метод success вызывается после успешной валидации только одного поля, а как сделать вызов для всех полей?

```
 $("form").validate({
  rules:{},
  messages:{},
  function(){}
 });
```

Comment: это Jquery validate ?

Comment: Да. Это jQuery validate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, `sucess` метод запускается каждый раз когда поле валидно становиться,и контекст функции `sucess` указывает именно на поле которое которое стало валидно. Вам необходимо использовать метод `submitHandler`, он стартует если все поля валидны, после события submit.

```js
  $('#form1').submit((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }).validate({
        submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!") },
        rules: {
            'field1': 'required',
            'field2': 'required'
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="form1" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="field1">
    <input type="text" name="field2">
    <input type="text" name="field3">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Если вы хотите каждый раз по клавише проверять то используйте просто keyup событие + метод валидации всей формы в целом,в этом примере отключил сообщения ошибки, можете настраивать через такие настройки - как только хотите, вариантов реализации просто масса !

```js
$('#form1').validate({
        errorPlacement: function(){
          return true
        },
        rules: {
            'field1': 'required',
            'field2': 'required'
        }
    })
    $('#form1').on('keyup',function (e) {
        console.log($(this).valid())
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="form1" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="field1">
    <input type="text" name="field2">
    <input type="text" name="field3">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: У меня в этой форме кнопка,которая меняет атрибут type на button или submit при каждом нажатии клавиши. Если все поля валидны то type=“submit” и форму можно отправить. А в вашем решении нужно сначала попытаться отправить форму, чтобы узнать валидна она или нет

Comment: @ArturHan на ваш вопрос `как вызвать функцию после успешной валидации ВСЕХ полей` я ответил, мысли читать никто не умеет. Для ваших целей надо другой подход использовать ща отредактирую новое накидаю...

Comment: @ArturHan обновил вам ответ. Алгоритм думаю должен быть понятен.